# TAB control background in ATL App, XP styles

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, xp-theme

I have an ATL application with a dialog containing a TAB control. The App uses a common controls manifest.

Under XP with visual styles, the tab control background is a different color than the dialog and the controls (mostly checkboxes), so it looks quite ugly.

[Screenshot](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/Uploads/175/ATLTAB.png)

How can I fix that?

Comment: “Perfect” answer for identical problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085427/common-controls-are-not-properly-painted-when-i-resize-window/58459674#58459674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042415/windows-xp-style-why-do-we-get-dark-grey-background-on-static-text-widgets) you could find answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

There is - apparently - one thing to do to get tab control pages colored correctly using XP visual styles.

In the WM_INITDIALOG handler for each page, call the uxtheme API [`EnableThemeDialogTexture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773320(VS.85).aspx)

With the `ETDT_ENABLETAB` flag this automatically changes the background color of the dialog and all its child controls to paint appropriately on a tab.

The dialog pages do not need any kind of transparent flag, or indeed any style bit set differently from previously. If you have overridden `WM_ERASEBKGND` or `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` in your pages DialogProc you will need to revert to default handling (return `FALSE`).

Answer (score 0):

The check boxes will post WM_CTLCOLORBTN notifications to their parent. If, for the checkbox control IDs, the parent window's message handler returns the result of

```
GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH)
```

then the check boxes should be drawn with a transparent background, which should give you the look you want.